# Stopping list requesting every item

Tags: list, apache-flex

I've got an `mx.controls.List` backed by a custom `IList` implementation. This contains several thousand items that are fetched asynchronously by returning a dummy item on `getItemAt`, firing off a request for the page that contains that data to the server, then triggering an update event when the response comes in.

The trouble we have is that users frequently rapidly scroll up and down the list, and currently the `List` is making a request for just about every item that's scrolled past. With a page size of 20, this can mean up to 1000 requests to the server for data that isn't even going to be seen.

Is there a way to make the `List` have a delay before requesting the items so it won't bother requesting it if it's off screen after tens of milliseconds?

I'm using Flex 3.

Comment: You use item renderer? Your dummy item can use Timer event to delay the call. But having too many timer events can reduce the performance of the system.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/10/26/infinitely-scrolling-lists-in-flex-applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to have the `IList` implementation add the uncached items into a fixed size buffer that gets processed 200ms after the first item is added, then group what's in the buffer into a single request to the server.